# Admin site is not accessible from subsites

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a magento multi site. We disable the default site and move the site and domain to another installation. Now the problem is that i cannot access admin from a sub site. What can be possible done in order to access the admin from a subsite?

Answer (score 0):

To access the admin from a sub-site, follow these steps:

Open the database for the sub-site in a database management tool (such as phpMyAdmin).

Locate the core_config_data table and search for the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url entries.

Change the URLs in these entries to the new admin URL. For example, if your new admin URL is https://subsite.example.com/admin, you would update the core_config_data entries to reflect this new URL.

Clear the cache by running bin/magento cache:clean.

Try accessing the admin using the new URL. You should now be able to access the admin from the sub-site.

If you are still unable to access the admin, you may need to check your server configuration to ensure that the sub-site is properly configured and accessible. You could also try clearing your browser cache or using a different browser to see if the issue is related to caching or cookies.